# Background thread throwing HibernateException - "No Hibernate Session bound to thread..."

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate

I need to create a process that will query a webservice to extract information, and then save the data in my database. However, because this process is very time-intensive, I would like to make it run in the background.

Currently, I have a `ProcessHandler` which is invoked by a button in the UI. This handler creates a `Thread` which should run the process in the background. However, I am getting `HibernateException` with the message `No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here`.

I have defined `ProcessHandler` in one of the config xml files (there are several) as follows (this is a very generic definition):

```
<bean class="com.project.ProcessHandler" parent="parentHandler" />
```

Inside `ProcessHandler`, the code to invoke this process is also very generic:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new WorkerThread(alphaManager, bravoManager, charlieManager));
t.start();
```

This is the current implementation of `WorkerThread`:

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private Manager alphaManager;
    private Manager bravoManager;
    private Manager charlieManager;

    public WorkerThread() {
        this.alphaManager = null;
        this.bravoManager = null;
        this.charlieManager= null;
    }

    public WorkerThread(Manager alphaManager, Manager bravoManager, Manager charlieManager) {
        this.alphaManager = alphaManager;
        this.bravoManager = bravoManager;
        this.charlieManager= charlieManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code to query webservice and extract data...

        saveToDbMethod(data);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    private void saveToDbMethod(String data) {
        // code to process data...

        alphaManager.save(entityA);
        bravoManager.save(entityB);
        charlieManager.save(entityC);
    }
}
```

The default constructor is a leftover from when I tried to define `WorkerThread` as a bean in (one of) my config xml files.

Can anyone help me by giving me some tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create the Thread manually and expecting it behave like a spring managed bean.

As the `ProcessHandler` is a legitimate bean, what i would do is following:

**1)** Create a seaparate service class which would have the managers as dependencies and that `@Transactional` method:

```
@Service
public class Service{

    private Manager alphaManager;
    private Manager bravoManager;
    private Manager charlieManager;

    public Service(Manager alphaManager, Manager bravoManager, Manager charlieManager) {
        this.alphaManager = alphaManager;
        this.bravoManager = bravoManager;
        this.charlieManager= charlieManager;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    private void saveToDbMethod(String data) {
        // code to process data...

        alphaManager.save(entityA);
        bravoManager.save(entityB);
        charlieManager.save(entityC);
    }
}
```

**2)** Inject the `Service` into the `ProcessHandler`:

```
<bean class="com.project.ProcessHandler" parent="parentHandler">
   <property name="service" ref="service">
</bean>
```

**3)** Finally pass the `Service` to the `WorkerThread`:

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private Service service;

    public WorkerThread(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code to query webservice and extract data...

        service.saveToDbMethod(data);
    }
}
```

and:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new WorkerThread(service));
t.start();
```

Now your operations should be transactional and within a session.

Comment: How should I define `service` in the config?

Comment: I defined it right below the definition for `ProcessHandler` as follows: `<bean id="service" class="com.project.Service" />` However, I get `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'service' is defined`

Comment: I have managed to solve my problem by following this solution, with some troubleshooting after that. I will detail my troubleshooting process in my subsequent comments.

Comment: I got this error - `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionExcept‌​ion: No bean named 'service' is defined`. I fixed it by defining `service` in a config file that would be read before where `ProcessHandler` was defined, as follows:

Comment: <bean id="service" class="com.project.Service">
        <property name="alphaManager" ref="alphaManager" />
        <property name="bravoManager" ref="bravoManager" />
        <property name="charlieManager" ref="charlieManager" />
    </bean>